# Returned value with exception handling using Python Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to run

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("MY_SELECTORS").click()
```

inside a test, but there are times that the element does not exist. if I did:

```
return = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("MY_SELECTORS").click()
```

and the element does not exist, would a value ( like an exception , or boolean FALSE) be returned? I have been reading [Docs » Locating Elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html), but although it details the error types, its not clear if a value is returned.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement has two parts, locating and clicking, there will be different exceptions and return types.

`find_element_by_css_selector()` returns webelement and may throw exception, while `click()` is void, exception might also be thrown.

So for example, if your locator is valid but results in no matching element, `NoSuchElementException` should be thrown. If your element is found, but not in clickable state, some type of exception will be thrown.

```
# untested Python pseudo code, only provides the logic
try:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("Selector doesn't exist").click()
except ElementNotVisibleException:
    print "ElementNotVisibleException"
except NoSuchElementException:
    print "NoSuchElementException"
except InvalidSelectorException:
    print "InvalidSelectorException"
except:
    print "Other exception types possible"
    raise
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! For my own information when you say "returns webelement and may throw exception" This cannot be captured in a variable ?

Comment: Return type and exception are different, why do you want to do that? It depends on what you want to get. You can have a method to return boolean or webelement.